# Where can I find the data that QGIS used to custom its menus as well as it's toolbars?

Tags: qgis

I have noted that QGIS uses some data to restore its menuitems as well as its toolbar items everytime  when it is started.And I have being trying to hunt them out in my hard disks but sadly failed...The whole registry has been searched with the key word "OSgeo" in the "find" dialog,but nothing found to be related with what i want,neither under the whole directory of "OSGeo4W". File types of "*.ini","*.xml","*.cfg" have been used for search. That has made me sad,you all know. So,any kindness to help ?

Comment: Don't be sad. QGIS stores all it's menu and toolbar settings in your User profile folder. Usually in C:\Users\<user>\.qgis - that .qgis folder holds the settings you've configured and plugins you've installed.

Comment: @Saultdon You should post this as an answer, not a comment since you seemed to have answered the question.

Comment: @SaultDon Thanks Saultdon. I do have checked the User profile folder before,but actually there only exists a empty gdal_pam folder,a python folder storing plugins I have installed,as well as two other files-qgis.db and symbology-ng-style.xml. Yet still none of any menu and toolbar settings could be seen there. Any further suggestion ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to run a stripped down version of QGIS with your own custom toolbars and menus is done in two steps:

1. Disabled unneeded widgets in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS\QGISCUSTOMIZATION\Customization`
2. Create a plugin that creates the extra menus and toolbars that you need.

The menus and UI widgets are stored in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS\QGISCUSTOMIZATION\Customization`.  Setting any of the items to false should be enough to hide them.  Deleting them doesn't work as QGIS will just reinsert a key with true when it loads next.  An example of a toolbar action is `mActionNewProject`

**QGIS 2.0 (1.9 dev) only**

In QGIS 2.0 you can also load with the `--customizationfile` flag which takes a ini version of what you see in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS\QGISCUSTOMIZATION\Customization`.  Using this option means that you can have different interfaces for different users which is great for training.  An example of doing this is:

```
qgis-dev --customizationfile myui.ini
```

The quickest way to get the ini file you need is exporting it from the the `Settings -> Customization` dialog.  Once you have this ini file you can open and edit it to disable any widgets you don't need to see.

[image]

Comment: Thanks Nathan.Yeah,I do did a silly thing while searching the registry,sorry about that.I have followed what you said,but just to find that keys under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\QuantumGIS\QGIS have nothing to do with Qgis's menu items or toolbar items.And Those under QGISCUSTOMIZATION do store interface state,but I also realized that though I turned some items off or set them to be false,and even deleted some of them,yet when I restarted my QGIS1.8,nothing changed !

Comment: Besides,my QGIS seems to reset settings if I make any changes to the customize.ini file which I saved form the Customsetting dialog and reload it.

Comment: See my edit for more details.

Comment: Thanks again for the detail,Nathan.Things goes like what you say if I just change the registry.So,do I have to change the Qgis source code and recompile it so as to get a real simplified customized menubars and toolbars ? I can do that,but I just wonder whether there is a easier method.You know,recompiling the source code is not an easy work.

Comment: Do you want your own custom menus? Or just a reduced QGIS interface?

Comment: Both.That means reducing menus unnecessary for my work and adding my own if possible.

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: Though still not what I really want,but it seems almost enough for the current work.Still,many thanks for your kindness and patience,Nathan.

Comment: I don't really know what you need then.